# How to "iterate" over a function whose type changes among iteration but the formal definition is the same

Tags: haskell, iteration

I have just started learning Haskell and I come across the following problem. I try to "iterate" the function `\x->[x]`. I expect to get the result `[[8]]` by

```
foldr1 (.) (replicate 2 (\x->[x])) $ (8 :: Int)
```

This does not work, and gives the following error message:

> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: `a ~ [a]`
>
> Expected type: `[a -> a]`
>
> Actual type: `[a -> [a]]`

I can understand why it doesn't work. It is because that `foldr1` has type signature `foldr1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> t a -> a`, and takes `a -> a -> a` as the type signature of its first parameter, not `a -> a -> b`

Neither does this, for the same reason:

```
((!! 2) $ iterate (\x->[x]) .) id) (8 :: Int)
```

However, this works:

```
(\x->[x]) $ (\x->[x]) $ (8 :: Int)
```

and I understand that the first `(\x->[x])` and the second one are of different type (namely `[Int]->[[Int]]` and `Int->[Int]`), although formally they look the same.

Now say that I need to change the 2 to a large number, say 100.

**My question is**, is there a way to construct such a list? Do I have to resort to meta-programming techniques such as Template Haskell? If I have to resort to meta-programming, how can I do it?

As a side node, I have also tried to construct the string representation of such a list and `read` it. Although the string is much easier to construct, I don't know how to `read` such a string. For example,

```
read "[[[[[8]]]]]" :: ??
```

I don't know how to construct the `??` part when the number of nested layers is not known *a priori*. The only way I can think of is resorting to meta-programming.

The question above may not seem interesting enough, and I have a "real-life" case. Consider the following function:

```
natSucc x = [Left x,Right [x]]
```

This is the `succ` function used in the [formal definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers). Again, I cannot simply `foldr1-replicate` or `!!-iterate` it.

Any help will be appreciated. Suggestions on code styles are also welcome.

**Edit**:
After viewing the 3 answers given so far (again, thank you all very much for your time and efforts) I realized this is a more general problem that is not limited to lists. A similar type of problem can be composed for each valid type of functor (what if I want to get `Just Just Just 8`, although that may not make much sense on its own?).

Comment: If the number of iterations `n` is statically known, maybe something can be done using type families (`Apply n [] a`), possibly exploiting singletons for naturals. Otherwise, you could create a large enough sum type to denote a nesting of lists, e.g. `data Value a = V a | L [Value a]` (which is a rose tree, roughly).

Comment: Thank you. I will check these options.

Comment: You can not create this as a list. So in that case you need to define a recursive data type (something like a tree, where you do not place values in the inodes).

Comment: Justin Le's posts on dependent types in Haskell are quite informative: https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-1.html

Comment: .Thank you for providing a site with excellent Haskell resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem indeed requires somewhat advanced type-level programming.

I followed @chi's suggestion in the comments, and searched for a library that provided inductive type-level naturals with their corresponding singletons. I found the [*fin*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0) library, which is used in the answer.

The usual extensions for type-level trickery:

```
{-# language DataKinds, PolyKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeFamilies #-}
```

Here's a [type family](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=type%20families#ghc-flag--XTypeFamilies) that maps a type-level natural and an element type to the type of the corresponding nested list:

```
import Data.Type.Nat

type family Nested (n::Nat) a where
    Nested Z a = [a]
    Nested (S n) a = [Nested n a]
```

For example, we can test [from ghci](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html?highlight=%3Akind#ghci-cmd-:kind) that

```
*Main> :kind! Nested Nat3 Int
Nested Nat3 Int :: *
= [[[[Int]]]]
```

([`Nat3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html#t:Nat3) is a convenient alias defined in `Data.Type.Nat`.)

And here's a newtype that wraps the function we want to construct. It uses the type family to express the level of nesting

```
newtype Iterate (n::Nat) a = Iterate { runIterate :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> Nested n a }
```

The *fin* library provides a really nifty [`induction1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html#v:induction1) function that lets us compute a result by induction on `Nat`. We can use it to compute the `Iterate` that corresponds to every `Nat`. The `Nat` is passed *implicitly*, as a [constraint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fin-0/docs/Data-Type-Nat.html#t:SNatI):

```
iterate' :: forall n a. SNatI n => Iterate (n::Nat) a
iterate' =
    let step :: forall m. SNatI m => Iterate m a -> Iterate (S m) a
        step (Iterate recN) = Iterate (\f a -> [recN f a])
    in  induction1 (Iterate id) step
```

Testing the function in ghci (using `-XTypeApplications` to supply the `Nat`):

```
*Main> runIterate (iterate' @Nat3) pure True
[[[[True]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you,  I will check this out and try to work out the problem that is mentioned at the end of my post.

Answer (score 5):

You'll certainly agree that `2 :: Int` and `4 :: Int` have the same type. Because Haskell is not [dependently typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type)<sup>†</sup>, that means `foldr1 (.) (replicate 2 (\x->[x])) (8 :: Int)` and `foldr1 (.) (replicate 4 (\x->[x])) (8 :: Int)` must have the same type, in contradiction with your idea that the former should give `[[8]] :: [[Int]]` and the latter `[[[[8]]]] :: [[[[Int]]]]`. In particular, it should be possible to put both of these expressions in a single list (Haskell lists need to have the same type for all their elements). But this just doesn't work.

The point is that you don't really want a Haskell list type: you *want* to be able to have different-depth branches in a single structure. Well, you *can* have that, and it doesn't require any clever type system hacks – we just need to be clear that this is not a list, but a *tree*. Something like this:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Rose [Tree a]
```

Then you can do

```
Prelude> foldr1 (.) (replicate 2 (\x->Rose [x])) $ Leaf (8 :: Int)
Rose [Rose [Leaf 8]]
Prelude> foldr1 (.) (replicate 4 (\x->Rose [x])) $ Leaf (8 :: Int)
Rose [Rose [Rose [Rose [Leaf 8]]]]
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, modern GHC Haskell has quite a bunch of dependently-typed features (see DaniDiaz' answer), but these are still quite clearly separated from the value-level language.</sub>

Comment: I checked in GHCi, I cannot put them in the same list. `a=(8 :: Int); b=[a,[a]]` is not allowed and GHCi complains about mismatching type.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's just what I said... Haskell lists are by design “flat-typed”, which IMO expresses naturally what the concept of a list _is_. But it's easy to define your own data types to support just the right amount of nesting possibility.

Comment: Thank you. I have misunderstood what you said at first glance.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose a very simple alternative which doesn't require any extensions or trickery: *don't* use different types.

Here is a type which can hold lists with any number of nestings, provided you say how many up front:

```
data NestList a = Zero a | Succ (NestList [a]) deriving Show
instance Functor NestList where
    fmap f (Zero a) = Zero (f a)
    fmap f (Succ as) = Succ (fmap (map f) as)
```

A value of this type is a church numeral indicating how many layers of nesting there are, followed by a value with that many layers of nesting; for example,

```
Succ (Succ (Zero [['a']])) :: NestList Char
```

It's now easy-cheesy to write your `\x -> [x]` iteration; since we want one more layer of nesting, we add one `Succ`.

```
> iterate (\x -> Succ (fmap (:[]) x)) (Zero 8) !! 5
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Zero [[[[[8]]]]])))))
```

Your proposal for how to implement natural numbers can be modified similarly to use a simple recursive type. But the standard way is even cleaner: just take the above `NestList` and drop all the arguments.

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is yet another way to view the problem. As for the natural number, I want to get the explicit expression in the form of sets, with sets replaced by lists. Your implementation is simple but does not provide any detail about the `Succ`. I will also try to write an explicit `show` for your data type so that I can see [[[[[8]]]]] without the  parentheses and constructor names. However if I **really** want to get "8" nested in the list for 100 times rather than something that looks similar but is not really a list, @danidiaz's answer still seems the only option so far.

Comment: Again I have to say that this construction is very clever, and elegant.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I'm not sure I understand your "if I **really** want to get '8' nested in the list for 100 times rather than something that looks similar but is not really a list" objection. There **really** is a list, nested 100-deep, with an `8` in the inner-most list here!

Comment: Yes, I can see it, although it is wrapped by some constructors. Maybe I should consider rewording.