# Use fold with a function that does not have the correct signature

Tags: haskell, signature, fold, type-mismatch

I have the following function:

```
brace_it :: a -> b -> (a, b)
brace_it a b = (a, b)
```

I can do `brace_it (brace_it (brace_it 1 2) 3) 4` with it an correctly get `(((1,2),3),4)`.

But I'd like to do  `foldl brace_it 0 [1,2,3,4]`. This is not possible however, as `brace_it` does not have the correct signature (it needs `b -> a -> b`). However conceptually it makes sense to fold a list with it, I think, to get the same result as manually applying it to `1`,...,`4`. Is it possible to build something to plug in-between `foldl`/ `foldr` and a function that does not actually have the correct type but still would in a way make sense to apply folds to?

Comment: No it does not, since the type depends on the value *at runtime* whereas types are something statically *at compile time*. If I make the list one element longer, it will be a different type.

Comment: which type is the one you are referring to now?

Comment: The output type of the hypthetical `foldl` function.

Comment: Okay, so you mean because the tuple would be one element longer and tuple type is determined also by the arity of the tuple, yes?

Comment: The arity will not be different. But for three elements, the output type would be `((a,a),a)` whereas for four, it would be `(((a,a),a),a)`. Those are two different types.

Comment: oh yea, right. But is this function that I have in mind possible at all then?

Comment: @Iotolmence: not with a tuple, but with a list-like data structure.

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate, but it shares a lot of features of the recent question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47844729/625403 - you may find some useful ideas there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is to do with types, namely that this leads to conflicting type signatures.

Let's take an example. If we take this:

```
foldl brace_it 0 [1] = (0,1) --(Not correct Haskell)
```

So, clearly, `foldl  brace_it 0 :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)`. However:

```
foldl brace_it 0 [1,2] = ((0,1),2) --(Not correct Haskell)
```

So, clearly, `foldl  brace_it 0 :: [Int] -> ((Int, Int), Int)`. This is spurious.

---

So, why isn't this theoretically possible? Because Haskell programs require you to know all types at compile time - you can't make a function that *could* construct an `(Int, Int)` or and `((Int, Int), Int)` - you need to do some acrobatics with types. For instance, you might construct a type that allows you to pair arbitrarily many things together:

```
data Pairs a = None | Pair a (Pairs a)
```

Then your `brace_it` function would become `brace_it a b = Pair a (Pair b None)`.

However, this is exactly equivalent to a normal Haskell list. So use a list.